# Pyautocad how to reset blocks in the ModelSpace

Tags: python, activex, pywin32, autocad

I wrote a code for adding attributes to block in a block collection and then I pass the ATTSYNC command.Then, I realized that sometimes, even if the new attributes are displayed in the block editor, they are not visible in the Model Space.

After several researches, I realized that before using the function AddAttribute I should reset the blocks.
I found the [ActiveX method](https://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-09C1799B-0DE5-43DB-82DF-D12F645EE1F7), and that is supposed to be just `block.ResetBlock` but it returns the following error: `NameError: Name ResetBlock not found`.
I access to the block in this way:

```
    for block in blocks:
        if not block.IsLayout:
            name = block.Name
            #legend is the dataframe that I use for assigning the new names
            if name in legend['misc-name'].unique():
                test_name = legend[legend['misc-name'] == name]['test-name'].to_string(index=False)
                block.ResetBlock
                dn_attribute = block.addAttribute(15, 0, "TEST", aDouble(15, 15, 0),"TEST", f"{test_name}")
                acad.doc.SendCommand('ATTSYNC' '\n' 'N' '\n' f'{block_name}''\n')
```